# Sensible one-to-one class relationship

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Let's say I have a class `Stock` representing some basic stock data, and then the additional class `StockDetails` providing some additional details of a specific stock.

**Stock.java**

```
public class Stock {

    private int stockId;
    private String stockCode;
    private String stockName;
    private StockDetail stockDetail;

    public Stock() {
    }

    public Stock(String stockCode, String stockName) {
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }

    // ...
}
```

**StockDetails.java**

```
public class StockDetail {

    private Stock stock; // yes or no?
    private String compName;
    private String compDesc;
    private String remark;
    private Date listedDate;

    public StockDetail() {
    }

    public StockDetail(String compName, String compDesc,
            String remark, Date listedDate) {
        this.compName = compName;
        this.compDesc = compDesc;
        this.remark = remark;
        this.listedDate = listedDate;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now I am not sure what would be the best way to design this kind of relationship.
My concerns are:

1. Should the `Stock` have a reference to it's `StockDetails` and `StockDetails` have a reference to it's `Stock`?
2. If the `StockDetails` doesn't have a reference to it's `Stock`, that quite makes no sense, because the `StockDetails` object is meaningless without the corresponding `Stock`. However, if it does have, it's pointless and weird to obtain the `Stock` from it's own details, ie. `stockDetails.getStock()`.
3. Should the `StockDetails` be an inner class of the `Stock`? This again is not ideal, because I would like to access the `StockDetails` class outside of the `Stock`.
4. It's even pointless to be able to instantiate a `StockDetails` object, without previously having a `Stock` object. The two should somehow be instantiated together, as they co-exist.

What would be the most sensible way to achieve that kind of relationship?

Comment: Why is this tagged effective-java?

Comment: It depends, as usually. If your StockDetail is a specialization of Stock, you could derive StockDetail from Stock. If Stock has one or more StockDetails, you could make it a composition. Think how you will use it in the program.

Comment: Reference to previous discussion on my similar question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45187206/uni-bi-direction-x-one-many-x-many-one-association-relationships

Comment: Could you provide a better outiline of what are,respectively, the responsabilities of Stock and StockDetails ?

Answer (score 2):

### Is a `StockDetail` a `Stock` ?

If `Stock` is a general concept that can exists on its own, but you need to specialize it for your needs with additional informations and functionality, then you could consider inheritance. The same object will then act for `Stock` and for `StockDetail`:

```
public class StockDetail extends Stock { ... }
```

Consequence:

- the class `Stock` is independent of class `StockDetail`
- class `StockDetail` depends on `Stock` that it specializes
- whenever you create an object,  you need to know for sure if it's a `Stock` or a `StockDetail`, and that this will not evolve over time.

### Is `SockDetail` a decorator of `Stock` ?

If a `StockDetail` should always behave as a `Stock`, but creation you can't tell which one to create, then you can think of using the [decorator pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html).

Initially you'd create a `Stock` object.  `StockDetail` would inherit from `Stock`, and hold a reference to the corresponding `Stock`.  Wherever you need the details, you'd use the decorator object.

Consequence:

- the class `Stock` is independent of class `StockDetail`
- class `StockDetail` depends on `Stock`
- you always first create a `Stock` object.
- you can create a  `StockDetail` object that refers to the `Stock` object, and use the `StockDetail` instead of the `Stock`.

### Is `StockDetail` a component of `Stock` ?

This would be the candidate by default according to the [principle of composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).  You just add a `StockDetail` member to the `Stock`.

If a `StockDetail` object is dependent of a `Stock` object, i.e. if it can't exist without the corresponding `Stock`, then the easiest approach would be to always access `StockDetail` via its owner, the `Stock` object.  In this case a reverse link would not be needed. In the DDD terminology, you'd say that both objects belong to the same [aggregate](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html) and `Stock` is the [aggregate root](http://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2016/07/14/DDD-Aggregate-Decoded-1).

Consequence:

- the class `StockDetail` is independent of class `Stock`
- class `Stock` depends on `StockDetail`
- you always first create a `Stock` object.
- you can create a `StockDetail` object for a `Stock` object.

### Are `Stock` and `StockDetails` independent but related objects  ?

If a `Stock` object has a `StockDetail` object, but if at the same time that `StockDetail` object could be used independently of the `Stock` object, you would need a bidirectional relation.

In this case you would need a reference in `Stock` to `StockDetail`, and a reference in `StockDetail` to `Stock`.  And you would need to ensure consistency of both links.

Consequence:

- Classes `Stock` and `StockDetail` are strongly coupled and interdependent
- When you access the object of one class, you can access to the corresponding object of the other class